# mysql saving and selecting many options

Tags: mysql

I’m developing an auctioning website. Each auction has a lot of options, that i want to be able to filter on the front-end.

I was wondering what is best practice in handling/storing these options (mostly booleans/checkboxes).

- Is it best practice to store them all in the same row ?
- **Or would it be better to store them all in one “auction_options” table?**

I guess the last option is the best one..but how would a query look like to:
select all auctions that have:

- state ohio
- state utah
- some other option

I just can't get my head around this. Is this even possible ?

**EDIT** --> the reply to comment field was not enough

I created 3 tables:

- auction table            -> a_id |   a_desc | etc
- a_options table          -> a_o_id | a_o_name | a_o_value
- a_options2auction table  -> id | a_id | a_o_id

when i run this query:

> > SELECT * FROM auctions as A
> >     INNER JOIN a_options2auction as B ON A.a_id = B.a_id 
> >     INNER JOIN a_options as C ON B.a_o_id = C.id
> >     WHERE c.value = 'groningen' OR c.value = 'utrecht'

it returns 2 rows that are both the same auction, that should not be possible :)

Comment: I recommend reading some basic ressources about database design. Maybe have a look at wikipedia first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `options` table that is connected M-N to the `auctions` table.

Between these two tables you should build another table to connect them.

```
Auctions 
    |
Auctions_options
    |
Options
```

So a query would be like this

```
SELECT * FROM Auctions as A 
INNER JOIN Auctions_Options as B ON A.id_auction = B.id_auction 
INNER JOIN Options as C ON B.id_Option = C.id_Option 
WHERE C.Option_name = 'State' AND (B.value = 'ohio' OR B.value='utah' OR B.value = '...')
```

This solutions allow you to add infinites options to an auction and store their value (each auction can have different options from the others too)

Comment: I guess this is what i am after for. Do i really need 2 tables for the options ? Isn't it possible to have 1 table with key pair values like this? option_id - option_auction_id - option_name - option_value. Or would this give me problems with searching?

Comment: I didn't understood well your question, but Using just 2 tables would make you need to insert the "same" options with different ids, identifying the option only by the name, wich means a potential incongruence of the database (I.E. if you insert an option named 'test' and the same but with 'tEsT' you need to handle this cases). Also, the query would be heavier for the system

Comment: hmm..i just tried this @ home. But when i do a mysql query it is returning duplicate rows because of the different options ? could you give me an example table setup ?

Comment: I've added the parenthesis to wrap the "or" filters, I didn't try that, but Auction_Options would be structured with an id_option,id_auction,value while table Options would be id_option, name, [other infos related to the option]

Comment: i edited the original post, the mini-markdown formatting in this field was not enough

Comment: You have to specify the options that you are looking for, like in my example i have a C.Option_name = 'State' to identify the option i want. Also, do something like `Select Auctions.*` and not `*` only

Comment: I did exactly as said, and ran your query: SELECT * FROM auctions as A 
INNER JOIN a_options_values as B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
INNER JOIN a_options as C ON B.o_id = C.id
WHERE C.name = 'provincie' AND (B.value = 'groningen' OR B.value='utrecht') But this still returns me duplicate records. Do i need to group them ?

Comment: are you SURE to have done `SELECT Auctions.* FROM...` and not `SELECT * FROM...` ? if it still duplicates try `SELECT DISTINCT Auctions.*` this is just my quick reply, dont blame me!

Answer (score 0):

For your second question ("how would a query look like to..") this should be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM auctions WHERE state=ohio OR state=utah
```

I don't really understand the first question though..could you please be clear? 
Anyway given a table 'auctions' I would store every single auction with all of its data (so I guess this is what you mean for booleans/checkboxes) in here..

but it all depends on what kind of 'options' you are storing ,quantity and you taste!If for example you need to store auction 'participants' option then go for creating another table 'partecipants' linked with foreign-keys id-fields to your 'auctions' table.

You may want to use [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The second option is better - there is no need to fill unnecessary fields. It will store only the options nedded for an auction.

As per the query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  Auctions
WHERE state_id in (1, 2)
```

The state_id will come from some check-boxes.